# Trying to change a button's contents doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
Something...
</head>

<body>

 <script>
$('#btnviewdetails').text('Save').button("refresh");
</script>   
<button id='btnviewdetails' type='button'>SET</button>


</body>

</html>
```

When I hit the button , the JS code is not invoked . What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need jQuery and jQuery UI to make that code work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind an event handler on the button. The function will be invoked when the button is pressed.

```
$('#btnviewdetails').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).text('Save');
});
```

Complete code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
Something...
</head>

<body>
<button id='btnviewdetails' type='button'>SET</button>
<script>
$('#btnviewdetails').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).text('Save');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```